# Login to SQL server on an application server with single user

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am making an application in C# that is supposed to work As CLIENT/SERVER architecture the application accesses to the server only to connect to the database. When I started developing the application I found that I had to make a connection string to access the database and then I made the following `$"Server = {server}; Database = {dataBase}; Trusted_Connection = True;"` which is working now and went to do a test on a machine where the local windows user does not have access to the SQL Server and hence I noticed that only

**user at the time of creating the SQL instance in the Mixed Mode option**

is one that have access to the SQL server if you are logged in to windows and are using the application. With little experience in developing such applications, I decided to come here to find help in how we can overcome this kind of challenges in desktop applications for .NET. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you want to connection testing from userside use of SQL instance?

Comment: i believe during installation  you haven't created a sql server authnetication userid and password ..you can follow the steps here to do the same https://www.supremainc.com/en/node/618

Comment: @Vishal Parmar yes it is what i want.

Comment: I have one idea maybe store the sa credentials in a shared file and any client desktop application that want to connect to the SQL Server must load the login credentials. Is it a right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows SQL server uses the currently logged in windows user [At the server] to authenticate a connection request. For remote computers, this may not be effective. Rather, it's better to use the username and password authentication method for remote hosts. Kindly make sure that your server is set to mixed mode authentication and follow the following steps.

1. Create a new user who uses username and password to login. Visit [https://www.supremainc.com/en/node/618] as suggested by Aqib
2. From the windows firewall, allow incoming connections to access SQL server from outside computers by setting inbound rules in your firewall to allow connections through SQL server port. You may need to check the port your SQL server is listening to though the default port is 1433.
   Visit [https://docs.syskit.com/spdockit/v7/faq/troubleshooting-sql-server-connection/inbound-traffic/] for instructions on how to setup the firewall
3. Make sure that the remote computer is connected to the server. You can do a simple ping to the server. You can use ip-address or server-name / url for checking the connection. [https://iihelp.iinet.net.au/How_to_run_a_ping_test]
4. Make sure your SQL server is started and run your application on the remote computer.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a SQL user, you first need to create a SQL user with the appropriate permissions (usually datareader and datawriter) on the database

[How to create a SQL user on a database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-database-user?view=sql-server-2017)

Then instead of using Trusted Connection, you need to explicitely define the username and password in the connection string like this:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

You can use [SQL connection strings website](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) as a reference for the various options