# A Network Related or Instance Specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, connection-string, desktop-application

This connection string is work fine on my System but when I'm going to run application in client machine after creating exe file. it give me this error shown in image.

[image: Picture of error]

Here is my Connection String:

```
Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename =|DataDirectory|\\pos_shoppy.mdf; Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30
```

Comment: And is SQL Server installed on that machine as well (considering that the connection name is "localDB", I assume it's pointing to the localhost).

Comment: Have you also checked TCP is enabled in MS SQL Configuration Manager, it's often disabled by default on SQL Express versions.

Comment: @WaynePhipps, localdb only supports local connections. Shared memory is used by default.

Comment: @Ali, do the Database files exist on the client machine?

Comment: I think this question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53059104/login-to-sql-server-on-an-application-server-with-single-user/53059605#53059605

Comment: @WaynePhipps yes it exist there

Comment: @WaynePhipps I had enable but not resolve this issue

Comment: @Larnu yes I install localdb in client machine the same version which I’m using but same issue